# How to add filter in computeService.Zones.List(project) Google Cloud Platform API

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to filter the zone list, in the Google Cloud Platform API

But I am not able to find any documentation in Google saying to put filter in the API:

```
req := computeService.Zones.List(project)
```

Above line of code will list the Zone in the Google Cloud Compute

in command line we can do the same

```
gcloud compute zones list --filter="name:us-"
```

Thanks,
Sid

Comment: I am not able to find any documentation, because I don't know which exact package is behind `coputeService`. How does your imports look like? Did you try godoc.org?

Comment: Hi, This is the import i am using "google.golang.org/api/compute/v1" For your reference : https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/zones/list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will help someone in case:

```
req := computeService.Zones.List("ProjectName")
if err := req.Filter("name=us*").Pages(ctx, func(page *compute.ZoneList) error {
//Your code
}
```